# Имитация текстового редактора на winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

Необходимо написать программу, имитирующую работу текстового редактора: в окне приложения
отображаются вводимые с клавиатуры символы, не используя для этого окно редактирования. Некоторые действия осуществляются при нажатии кнопок мыши, ряд настроек осуществляется в диалоговых окнах, вызываемых из меню. В данном случае правая и левая кнопки мыши вставляют в текущую (левая) и указанную мышью (правая) позицию слова (разные для обеих кнопок). Эти слова выбираются в диалоговом окне из предложенного списка или вводятся там же в окне редактирования.

Пока сделал только простейший вывод строки на экран. Я буквально беру и вывожу на экран строку. Возможно, что это вообще не лучший вариант для данного задания, но использовать окно редактирования нельзя по условию, а иначе я не умею XD. Как с диалоговыми окнами работать я, честно говоря, не в курсе.

Вот чистый обработчик событий:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    static String str;
    int x, y;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Разобрать выбор в меню:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_CHAR:
        str += (TCHAR)wParam;
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        break;
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, str.data(), str.size());
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0); break;
    default: return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ну и код целиком:

```
// TextRed.cpp : Определяет точку входа для приложения.
//

#include "framework.h"
#include "TextRed.h"
#include <xstring>
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR, std::char_traits<TCHAR>,
    std::allocator<TCHAR> > String;
#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100


// Глобальные переменные:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // текущий экземпляр
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // Текст строки заголовка
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // имя класса главного окна

// Отправить объявления функций, включенных в этот модуль кода:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Разместите код здесь.

    // Инициализация глобальных строк
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_TEXTRED, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Выполнить инициализацию приложения:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TEXTRED));

    MSG msg;

    // Цикл основного сообщения:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  ЦЕЛЬ: Регистрирует класс окна.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_TEXTRED));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_TEXTRED);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   ФУНКЦИЯ: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   ЦЕЛЬ: Сохраняет маркер экземпляра и создает главное окно
//
//   КОММЕНТАРИИ:
//
//        В этой функции маркер экземпляра сохраняется в глобальной переменной, а также
//        создается и выводится главное окно программы.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Сохранить маркер экземпляра в глобальной переменной

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  ЦЕЛЬ: Обрабатывает сообщения в главном окне.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - обработать меню приложения
//  WM_PAINT    - Отрисовка главного окна
//  WM_DESTROY  - отправить сообщение о выходе и вернуться
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    static String str;
    int x, y;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Разобрать выбор в меню:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_CHAR:
        str += (TCHAR)wParam;
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        break;
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, str.data(), str.size());
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0); break;
    default: return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}



// Обработчик сообщений для окна "О программе".
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал ф-ию под правую кнопку мыши:

```
case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
        x = LOWORD(lParam);
        y = HIWORD(lParam);
        hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        TextOut(hdc, x, y, l_str, _tcsclen(l_str));
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
        break;
```

И под левую

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        str += l_str;
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        break;
```

Добавил обработчики нажатия на кнопки изменения слова для вставки:

```
 case ID_32771:
           l_str = _T("Click");
           r_str = _T("Click");
           break;

        case ID_32772:
            l_str = _T("Hello");
            r_str = _T("Hello");
            break;

        case ID_32773:
            l_str = _T("World");
            r_str = _T("World");
            break;
```